# Working on a customized Task Manager in WPF .NET Framework, how do I prevent processes from duplicating?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

namespace CustomizedWPFTaskManager
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //Load Function
            OnLoad();
        }

        private void OnLoad()
        {
            System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = new          System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
            dispatcherTimer.Tick += dispatcherTimer_Tick;
            dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2);
            dispatcherTimer.Start();
        }

        private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //- Refresh process list
            Process pList = new Process();
            List<String> procList = new List<string>(new string[] { "" });


            foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcesses())
            {
                try
                {
                    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(p.MainModule.FileName);

                    procList.Add(fi.Name);
                    TaskViewBox1.Items.Add(fi.Name);
                }
                catch { }
            }

            countLabel.Content = TaskViewBox1.Items.Count + " PROCESSES    RUNNING";
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I have so far, but my problem is processes will keep adding even though they are already their (duplicates). Also I am new to this, my boss has been teaching me to help out around the shop. He wanted me to learn WPF as well. This was what I thought a good first project, any help on how to remove duplicates? Also if its not to much can you explain what you did a little but so I am not just copying the code but actually learning it for next time.

Comment: You're adding all process names to the Items collection on each call of the `dispatcherTimer_Tick` method, so what are you expecting? Probably just call `TaskViewBox1.Items.Clear()` before the foreach loop.

Comment: ^ thanks so much man, that helped. When putting it right before the foreach loop, it allows the program to still use the tick to refresh while also clearing it every two second correct? It worked like a charm for me but I also like to learn what its doing since conceptually I get things better.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a look at a very basic example that makes use of the MVVM achitectural pattern.

First the view model. It has a `Processes` property, which is an `ObservableCollection<Process>` and a `Tick` event handler of a `DispatcherTimer`, which updates the collection.

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Process> Processes { get; }
        = new ObservableCollection<Process>();

    public ViewModel()
    {
        var timer = new DispatcherTimer { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2) };
        timer.Tick += UpdateProcesses;
        timer.Start();
    }

    private void UpdateProcesses(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var currentIds = Processes.Select(p => p.Id).ToList();

        foreach (var p in Process.GetProcesses())
        {
            if (!currentIds.Remove(p.Id)) // it's a new process id
            {
                Processes.Add(p);
            }
        }

        foreach (var id in currentIds) // these do not exist any more
        {
            Processes.Remove(Processes.First(p => p.Id == id));
        }
    }
}
```

Now the view. It is a simple ListBox that shows the `Id` and `ProcessName` of the collection of Processes. Its `ItemsSource` is bound to the `Processes` property of the view model.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Processes}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}" Width="50"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ProcessName}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Finally, an instance of the view model has to be assigned to the DataContext of the MainWindow. This can be done in XAML

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:ViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

or in code behind

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = new ViewModel();
}
```